# Android emulator is not starting?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator

[image]

I am not able to unlock the emulator, not able to create new emulator?
what is solution for this ?

Comment: Swipe the symbol with the mouse to the right or kill the emulator and try after that to start a new one.

Comment: i am not able to swipe, its not working, restarted the eclipse still not working, and not able to create new emulator..

Comment: The emulator is detached from the eclipse ide, try to kill the process with a task manager or a kill signal.

Comment: adb -s emulator-5554 emu kill see https://devmaze.wordpress.com/2011/12/12/starting-and-stopping-android-emulators/

Comment: i killed the process with a task manager , still not starting

Comment: [2015-04-09 14:02:29 - Emulator] ##KBD: Full queue, lose event when i am trying to swipe , these lines are displaying in console

Comment: Delete this emulator and launch the application, then create an emulator when your ide asks you to create.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always run `adb -e shell input keyevent 82` to unlock a device via the terminal.

About not being able to create a new emulator: you should check the precise error message, this should give you a clue to what the exact problem is.